# Is use of schools' rooftops a common thing in Japanese culture or just a cliché?

Tags: tropes

In many manga and anime involving modern schools, there is a scene on or at least showing the rooftop of the building. It is a place students can freely go to, often depicted with having a bust-height railing along the edge and the typical 'small building' from which you leave the school building, often also having a ladder to get up (nonetheless being a popular 'hiding' or 'being alone' spot even without one).

I wanted to ask: is this one of many clichés about Japanese culture that appear throughout the whole media type, or are they a common thing in Japanese schools?

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/why-there-are-many-scenes-in-anime-that-take-place-on-the-roof

Comment: Shoot, wanted to add it in but forgot to. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sorry, but they look like just a cliché....

From this Quora answer (yes Quora!):

> While many Japanese schools do have flat rooftops, they are usually off-limits and properly locked. So, eating your lunch on the roof or confessing your love at sunset up there... not gonna happen.

Source: [Quora](http://qr.ae/R4wrwo)

Another source directly from our own Anime and Manga StackExchange: [AM StackExchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6461/16344)

A quick Google search also reveals this (unfortunate) truth.

Comment: Seems like these two answers contradict each other.. While both imply access is not allowed per the rules, the [answer on the other question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6461/16344) states rooftops are seldom locked. However, the Quora answer implies they are most-always locked.